# remove unwanted space in header/footer

Tags: c#, ms-word

I'm currently writing a program in C# that programmatically insert table in header/footer for MSWORD 2003.

My problem is after creation of table, there is unwanted space after the table. I have already manually fix or delete it using msword, but I cannot remove that extra space. Because of that the cursor was not start where the point of top margin is.

I've already google it but cannot find any solution. Any help will appreciate. Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also set the Text Wrapping property of the table to AROUND instead of NONE. this will cause the following para mark to float to the right of the table, not below it, so you won't get the extra line, and you won't have to resort to 1 pt hacks (which work, but I try to avoid them when possible).

It's easy to do in Word manually, but A quick try at recording a macro to do it failed so I'm not sure of the Object Model method.

Comment: This correct when editing the word manually.
Then I record it in a macro and I get this:

    Selection.Tables(1).Rows.WrapAroundText = True

I try to code in C# using this
    ....some code
    tables.Rows.WrapAroundText = 1;

but this not work.
I'm new to C# so I guess something wrong with my code.

I also refer to this link:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsto/thread/fc0f5799-7729-4447-83e7-f059a5d3ef56

For now I'm planning to use a template to minimize my code and
set settings that I can't do with C#.

Well thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

By default there is a new line after a table in MS Word. As a workaround you could try to set the font size after the table to 1.